# Load properties file in a java servlet deployed in JBoss as a war

Tags: java, jboss, properties

I have a servlet deployed as a war in JBoss 4.0.2.  I have a properties file for the deployed application.  Where should I put this file? Under the conf directory in the jboss server\default\conf folder? How do I load that properties file in a portable manner?

Comment: The project that required this got canceled so I never followed up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To load that properties file in a **portable** manner, the best way would be to put it on the classpath of the web application (either in a JAR under `WEB-INF/lib/` or under `WEB-INF/classes/` or on the app server classpath if you want to be able to edit that file without repackaging your web application) and to use [`Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

The following code gets an `InputStream` for a property file which resides in the same package as the servlet in which the code is executed:

```
InputStream inStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                 .getResourceAsStream("myfile.properties");
```

Then, [`load(InputStream)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) it into a [`Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object (skipping Exception handling):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(inStream);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just get hold of the servletContext and then

```
InputStream stream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/log4j.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(stream);
```

This will always work, regardless of whether you deploy a war or exploded war.

Answer (score 2):

If the properties file can be deployed along with the application make it part of your source tree. This will result in the properties file to be in the WEB-INF/classes folder.

This can then be read using

```
Properties properties = loadProperties("PropertyFileName.properties", this.getClass());
...

public static Properties loadProperties(String resourceName, Class cl) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    ClassLoader loader = cl.getClassLoader();
    try {
        InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
        if (in != null) {
            properties.load(in);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best place to put it is under the web-apps' own doc-root, like "./WEB-INF/myapp.properties", i.e. relative to where the servlet container unpacked your `.war` or `.ear` file. You can provide the properties file directly in the `.war`.

The `ServletContext` has a method `getRealPath(String path)` that returns the actual path in the filesystem. Using the real path you can load it in a `Properties` collection.

**Update**
The code in your comment tries to lookup real path for "/", you should ask for the relative path to your properties file, as in:

```
String propertiesFilePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/application.properties");
Properties props = properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFilePath));
```

Comment: So I tried the following:

String propertiesFilePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + File.separator + "WEB-INF" + File.separator + "application.properties";
properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFilePath));

I get a FileNotFoundException. I don't see what I did wrong.