# How to portably read configuration data from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, properties, servletconfig

I'm writing a Java servlet that needs to read some site-specific
configuration data; I would like it to be easily accessible/modifiable
by the sysadmins at deployment time.  There is no sensible default,
so the data *has to* be provided by the site admin.
It consists of a few string key/value pairs (think Properties).
It would only be read once (at initialization time).

I'm aware of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015384/load-properties-file-in-a-java-servlet-deployed-in-jboss-as-a-war)
and the `ServletContext.getInitParameter()` mechanism, but as far as
my understanding goes, they require the data to be bundled in the
servlet package (either as a properties file, or specified in the
`web.xml`), which makes it inconvenient to upgrade the servlet code.

Is there any "standard" interface for a servlet to get this kind of
key/value configuration data?  It would be ok if the programming
interface is the same everywhere, but the actual way of setting the
configuration data depends on the actual servlet container being used.

I'm looking preferably at portable solutions, but I'd be content with
something that only works in Tomcat and Jetty.

Comment: The recommended solution is to use JNDI as vanje answered below. Considering he also has double the upvotes as the 2nd best answer, please give him the credit he is due and mark his answer correct.

Comment: @Yoely: Done.  The situation was not so clear-cut months ago when I posted the question...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The recommended way to configure an application server for a web application is per JNDI.

Every application server (including Jetty and Tomcat) allows you to configure JNDI parameters.

For Jetty you can add the following to your jetty.xml to add the JNDI parameter `param.file`:

```
<!--  JNDI java:comp/env --> 
<New id="param.file" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.EnvEntry">
  <Arg>param.file</Arg> 
  <Arg type="java.lang.String"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>etc/config.properties</Arg> 
  <Arg type="boolean">true</Arg> 
</New>
```

Then in your servlet you can read the JNDI parameter:

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

...

public Object readJndi(String paramName) {
  Object jndiValue = null;
  try {
    final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    jndiValue = ic.lookup("java:comp/env/" + paramName);
  } catch (NamingException e) {
    // handle exception
  }
  return jndiValue;
}


public String getConfigPath() {
  return (String) readJndi("param.file");
}
```

The way to set JNDI values differs for other application servers but the code to read the configuration is always the same.

Answer (score 4):

The **Servlet init parameters are the right (and standardized) way** of defining properties which can be configured by the administrator. Many of the application servers provide a GUI backend where the parameters can be configured.

For an example for Tomcat, see [Defining Tomcat servlet context parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626018/defining-tomcat-servlet-init-parameters)

Comment: +1 preferably via `context-param` (the JNDI route is good too, I think).

Comment: In Jetty, servlet init parameters can be defined or overridden in the [override-web.xml file](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/override+web.xml)

Answer (score 3):

- Configure the external location of the properties - either via a jvm argument (when starting the servlet container), or in the web.xml
- in the external location use `config.properties` and read it with [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Comment: Or just add its path to the runtime classpath and load it from the classpath.

Comment: Thanks: nice and simple. But, unless I misunderstand, this would require me to embed an absolute pathname into the web.xml, or the sysadmin to hack the JVM/servlet container startup script to define a property. Both solutions seem to have drawbacks...

Answer (score 0):

You may take Preferences or hack with user.home, user.dir, etc. But for a few key/value keep things simple.

Write a small Singleton to wrap around Properties and load them from a fix & absolute location

```
public class LocalConfig extends Properties {

  public static LocalConfig $ = new LocalConfig();

  private LocalConfig() throws IOException {
    load(new File("/etc/myconfig.properties"));
  }

}
```