# Accessing properties file in a war

Tags: java, web-applications, properties, war

I'm trying to access my properties file in a war. The code is working, but when i'm exporting the code into a war and use a POST (with an accepted input) using Fiddler, it cannot find the config.properties. (NullPointerException)

The input and webservice are running correctly. Just trying to figure out a way to edit my properties while using a war.

Some facts:

- I've made a RetreivePropertiesClass. This uses:

  ```
  properties.load(this.getClass()
                      .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.properties"));
  ```
- My properties file path:

  ```
  /com.webapp/WebContent/WEB-INF/config.properties
  ```
- I'm trying to use the properties data in:

  ```
  String url = RetreiveProperties.getUrl();
  String driver = RetreiveProperties.getDriver();
  String username = RetreiveProperties.getUsername();
  String password = RetreiveProperties.getPassword();

  // line below causes the NullPointerException
  Class.forName(driver);
  ```
- Getter used:

  ```
  public static String getDriver() {
  return driver = properties.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
  }
  ```
- When the war is deployed, the properties file is in:

  ```
  webapps\com.webapp1\WEB-INF\config.properties
  ```
- Config.properties:

  ```
  jdbc.url = jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:2222/gisdb
  jdbc.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
  jdbc.username = postgres
  jdbc.password = admin
  ```

I already tried to work out the examples given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015384/load-properties-file-in-a-java-servlet-deployed-in-jboss-as-a-war) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291398/java-accessing-properties-file-inside-a-war). Keeps giving the NullPointerException because the properties file isn't loaded.

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Cheers!

[image: NullPointer in TomCat8]

Comment: What is the path of the properties file if you check inside of the packaged war file?

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention it. It's in C:\Users\myusername\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.21-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\com.webapp1\WEB-INF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is a static method, the getClass() method will be failed, and prompts “Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object“.

Instead, you should use *CurrentClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream.*

Source: [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-getresourceasstream-in-static-method/)

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to load the properties file from the classpath, it must be in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory inside of your war. (Or inside a jar inside of `WEB-INF/lib` ). The `WEB-INF` directory itself is not on the classpath.

If you make sure the file ends up as `WEB-INF/classes/config.properties` your above code should work if you change the `getResourceAsStream` call to `getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")`

Comment: I put my properties file in: C:\Users\myusername\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.21-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\webapps\com.webapp1\WEB-INF\classes\com\webapp. 

I'm using properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/classes/com/webapp/config.properties")); to get the file, but it still doesn't work. Did I make a typo?

Comment: P.S. The C:\ address is the dir where my properties file is stored when I look into the war file.

Comment: @Camelaria If you put it in that path you need to call getResourceAsStream("/com/webapp/config.properties")

Comment: Hmm, changed the loader to /com/webapp/config.properties. Still get a NullPointerException at Class.forName(driver);. This is where I use a properties value for the first time.

Comment: @Camelaria please post the stack trace. Is it actually the stream you get as null or something else?

Comment: Added stacktrace from Tomcat server in question. com.webapp.ConverterClass.getDetectors(ConverterClass.java:31) is the driver value.